# Subsetting one matrix by another matrix

Tags: r, apply

I have a matrix of Booleans, and I want to iterate through the rows of another matrix, for each row returning the contents of the column with an index corresponding to the column which contains `TRUE` in the Boolean matrix. Here's my solution so far...

**Example**

```
set.seed(0)
knl <- c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
A = matrix(knl, nrow=3, ncol=6, byrow=TRUE)
B = matrix(rnorm(18),3,6)

fn <- function(x, vec) {return(x[,vec])}
v = unlist(apply(A, 1, which)))
mapply(fn, x=as.data.frame(t(B)), vec=v)
```

**Desired Output**

Not sure how it would be formatted, but something like this.

```
# [1,]
# -1.1476570
# -0.2894616
# -0.2992151
# [2,]
# 1.2724293
# 0.4146414
# -1.5399500
# [3,]
# 1.2724293
# 0.4146414
# -1.5399500
```

But somehow messed up the dimensions, can't figure this one out.

```
Error in x[, vec] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Any obvious red flags? A simpler, better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the TRUE columns in each row of A first, then for each of those columns, extract that column from B

```
lapply(apply(A, 1, which), function(i) B[,i,drop=FALSE])
```

Comment: Beautiful! This is the one-line solution I was looking for - it doesn't depend on the number of rows or columns of either matrix. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

`mapply` based solution is worth considering in this scenario. The logic iterate over all indexes of rows (1 to max-row). For each element in a row which contains `TRUE` return the column from `B`. It can be established as `B[,A[x,]]`.

```
mapply(function(x)B[,A[x,]], 1:nrow(B))
#            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
# [1,] -1.1476570  1.2724293  1.2724293
# [2,] -0.2894616  0.4146414  0.4146414
# [3,] -0.2992151 -1.5399500 -1.5399500
```

**Data**

```
set.seed(0)
knl <- c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,
         FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
A = matrix(knl, nrow=3, ncol=6, byrow=TRUE)
B = matrix(rnorm(18),3,6)
```